# Postfix/Dovecot support multiple domains

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, postfix

I have a server running Postfix/Dovecot with a MySQL back-end which is configured to use the domain name 'olddomain.com'. I am migrating everything to use another domain 'newdomain.com' and Postfix/Dovecot/Postfixadmin all need to be migrated too. However I need to support both domain names for a while and this should be transparent for users. Emails that are send to 'username@olddomain.com' need to arrive at 'username@newdomain.com', users need to be able to log in (Postfixadmin/Dovecot) with 'username@olddomain.com' and 'username@newdomain.com', etc.

I cannot figure out how to do this to support the named use cases, so any help would be appreciated.

Relevant config stuff:

**postconf -n**

```
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
html_directory = no
mail_owner = postfix
mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mynetworks_style = host
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = no
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domain_maps.cf
relayhost = *******
sample_directory = /etc/postfix
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail
setgid_group = postdrop
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql_virtual_domain_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/sql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

**sql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf:**

```
password = ****
hosts = localhost
dbname = pf_adm
query = SELECT CONCAT(maildir, 'Maildir/') AS maildir FROM mailbox WHERE username='%s' AND active = '1'
```

**sql_virtual_domain_maps.cf:**

```
user = ****
password = ****
hosts = localhost
dbname = pf_adm
query = SELECT domain FROM domain WHERE domain='%s' AND backupmx = '0' AND active = '1'
```

**sql_virtual_alias_maps.cf:**

```
user = ****
password = ****
hosts = localhost
dbname = pf_adm
query = SELECT goto FROM alias WHERE address='%s' AND active = '1'
```

**doveconf -n**

```
# 2.1.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 3.4.5-hardened i686 Gentoo Base System release 2.1 ext4
auth_verbose = yes
first_valid_gid = 12
first_valid_uid = 8
last_valid_gid = 12
last_valid_uid = 8
mail_gid = 12
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/%d/%n/Maildir/:INDEX=/var/mail/%d/%n/indexes
mail_uid = 8
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
postmaster_address = postmaster@olddomain.com
protocols = imap
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mail
    mode = 0600
    user = mail
  }
}
ssl_cert = 

Bonus info (if needed), users are stored like this:


+------------------------+-------------------------+------------+---------------+
| username               | maildir                 | local_part | domain        |
+------------------------+-------------------------+------------+---------------+
| username@olddomain.com | olddomain.com/username/ | username   | olddomain.com |
+------------------------+-------------------------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I don't know if postfix will explode if you do this, but wouldn't having both the olddomain and newdomain accounts point to the same `maildir` have the same mail available in both accounts?

Comment: @DerfK I guess I could make a symlink from `${mail_spool_directory}/olddomain.com` to `${mail_spool_directory}/newdomain.com` but this would only make the mail available if I duplicate each account with '@newdomain.com' instead of '@olddomain.com'. I rather not recreate each account.

Answer (score 3):

Persistently requiring the full domain name for every address is biting you in the backside here.

It really isn't necessary since all you have is the one domain, so a simple solution would be to alter the SQL lookups to act on the localpart only.

Add the new domain to virtual_mailbox_domains and perform only a localpart lookup on virtual_mailbox_maps.

Both domains and all users in it will be accepted and delivered.

Using a complicated query for virtual_mailbox_domains isn't likely to help, either.
Just list the domain(s) in virtual_mailbox-domains:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = olddomain, newdomain
```

Comment: So how should a query for a user look? I'm guessing `SELECT CONCAT(maildir, 'Maildir/') AS maildir FROM mailbox WHERE local_part='%s' AND active = '1'` but this won't work when a user logs in with an email address, right? I also don't get what you mean with 'using the same query'.

Comment: I have no idea what "log in" means to you; postfix does not log users in.

Comment: I should have noted I am using Postfixadmin and Dovecot too.

Comment: Those are unrelated to the postfix MTA. If you need help with them, provide adequate information: the full output of `postconf -n`, `doveconf -n`, and relevant log messages that show what is going wrong.

Comment: I have modified the question accordingly, if more info is needed I am happy to supply it.