# Postfix : multi user one maildir

Tags: postfix

I have a problem : I have two domains: `domain1.tld` and `domain2.tld`.

All my users are created in `domain1.tld` and I would like my users to be able to use `user1@domain1.tld` or `user1@domain2.tld` to log-in and to check their emails.

Do you think it's possible?

I use Postfix with Dovecot and MySQL.

Sorry for my english it's not my native language.

Thanks in advance

Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem

I created all my users on domain2.tld who existed on domaine1.tld
and after I done a symbolic link between domain1.tld and domain2.tld ( ln -s domaine1.tld domaine2.tld )

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really about dovecot, not postfix, if you're talking about users retrieving mail.

See this:
[Postfix/Dovecot support multiple domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/448198/postfix-dovecot-support-multiple-domains)

Comment: but it doesn't solve mine, because some of my users can have the same local_part id...